# SWIG, Python, C with void return arguments

Tags: python, c, swig, void-pointers

I have the following function constructor in C header file:

```
int my_fun(int i, void *a, void *b, void *c);
```

in order to provide some context, I am providing a C code implementation that illustrates how it might be used:

```
int error;
double *a, *b, *c;

int i = 1;
int num = 500;
int num_dim = 2;

a = (double *) calloc(num, sizeof(double));
b = (double *) calloc(num, sizeof(double));
if (num_dim >= 3)
   c = (double *) calloc(num, sizeof(double));
else
   c = 0

 error = my_fun(i,a,b,c);
 error = my_fun(i,NULL,b,NULL); /*read only b*/
```

I would like to know how to implement this in the SWIG interface file.  I have used `typemaps.i` for other types of pointer return arguments, but it does not appear to have support for `void*`.

Answer (score 3):

SWIG provides a file, [carrays.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_carrays) which is well matched to `calloc`. You can use the macro `%array_functions` or `%array_class` to expose some helper functions that wrap C style arrays to your target language. (You can still use both even though you're using C). I made the following interface that wraps and defines a simple `my_fun` all at once with `%include`:

```
%module test

%include "carrays.i"

%array_functions(double,DoubleArray)

%inline %{
  int my_fun(int i, void *a, void *b, void *c) {
    printf("my_fun: i=%d, a=%p, b=%p, c=%p\n",i,a,b,c);
    return 0;
  }
%}
```

If you want to support more types than just `calloc(num, sizeof(double))` you'll need to add more `%array_functions` to your interface file. carrays.i also generates functions for getting and setting specific values in the array as well as deleting them

After that your example usage becomes the following in Python:

```
import test

i = 5
num = 500
num_dim = 2

a = test.new_DoubleArray(num)
b = test.new_DoubleArray(num)
c = None
if num_dim >= 3:
  c =  test.new_DoubleArray(num)

error = test.my_fun(i,a,b,c)
error = test.my_fun(i,None,b,None)

# Beware of the exceptions, you need a finally: really
test.delete_DoubleArray(a)
test.delete_DoubleArray(b)
test.delete_DoubleArray(c)
```

I compiled and ran this on my system with:

```
swig -python -Wall test.i 
gcc -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 test_wrap.c -shared -o _test.so -Wall -Wextra
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python2.7 run.py
```

Which gave the following output:

```
my_fun: i=5, a=0x2767fa0, b=0x2768f50, c=(nil)
my_fun: i=5, a=(nil), b=0x2768f50, c=(nil)
```

Since the "array" here is just a proxy to a real chunk of memory allocated in C with `calloc` any changes you make to the array will be visible from Python the next time you read it.

---

If you use `%array_class` instead of `%array_functions` the Python code becomes:

```
import test

i = 5
num = 500
num_dim = 2

a = test.DoubleArray(num)
b = test.DoubleArray(num)
c = None
if num_dim >= 3:
  c =  test.DoubleArray(num)

error = test.my_fun(i,a.cast(),b.cast(),c.cast() if c else None)
error = test.my_fun(i,None,b.cast(),None)
```

Notice that here the reference counting has removed the need to explicitly delete the array, solving the problem with exceptions by deferring to reference counting. The `%array_class` also provides implementations of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` so it can be sub-scripted like any other array or container in Python would. (No bounds checking though, just like C)